# Can not obtain long-lived token instagram

Tags: javascript, angular, token, instagram

I wrote code according to the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/ But obtaining of token implemented on client side. It was implemented like this cause client should chose the app by himself. The question of protecting data is solved by the limited access for users to client side. **The problem is that the token is not living long.**  Any ideas? My implementation is below 
 Step 1. The activation of Facebook enter button with use of  appId and appSecret

```
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
(window as any).fbAsyncInit = () => {
  FB.init({
    appId: this.appId,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v7.0'
  });

  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};
```

Step 2. Sign in Facebook and choose the app
Step 3. Obtaining the long-lived token for user
Step 4. Obtaining the app list of user via long-lived token that we obtained from the previous step

```
private async getLongLiveToken(userId: string, shortLiveToken: string): Promise<string> {
    const userTokenResponse = await this.callFacebookAPI('/oauth/access_token', {
      grant_type: 'fb_exchange_token',
      client_id: this.appId,
      client_secret: this.appSecret,
      fb_exchange_token: shortLiveToken
    }).toPromise();

    if (userTokenResponse.error) {
      alert(userTokenResponse.error.message);
    }

    return userTokenResponse.access_token;
  }
```